# What exactly is a log drain

Tags: logging

I was looking around some source code on GitHub, and I found the source for a "log drain". I was interested in what that was so I Googled it. All I got, however were a bunch of links to Heroku. What is a log drain, and what is it used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a homebrew synonym for [log handler](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial) (an entity that receives logging events and writes them down as resulting text/whatever).<sup>1</sup> The original term from `log4j` is "[appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html)".

The wording is likely an analogy of a more general notion, "[event sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sink_%28computing%29)". It's as if a logging event "emerges" at a logger, goes through other loggers and filters, then "sinks" into a handler.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Decisive evidence is the "[Slight rename. heroku-log-drain -> heroku-log-store](https://github.com/rwdaigle/heroku-log-store/commit/344b23685f64cf4d5a0c3986d57d3c64144ef262)" commit log entry.
(Yes, I'm watching an Ace Attorney game walkthrough at the moment :^) )</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would submit that a log drain is an integration between logging middleware and a third-party monitoring service, like datadog.

[Example](https://docs.netlify.com/monitor-sites/log-drains/)